# React - mousemove event isn't working correctly

Tags: reactjs, events, event-handling, mouseevent, create-react-app

I'm creating a range slider and this is how it works: i've added onMouseDown event to the slider - in the function, i've attached onMouseMove and onMouseUp events to document - that's it! Simple. It works perfect on codepen.io but not locally.
I expected to see the log "down" in the console, then a lot of "move" and finally get the "up" message.
But the events showing up at the same time after release the mouse button.

console log:

[image]

Where could be the problem? How to fix if?

My project is created with create-react-app. I ran it in Google Chrome and Opera.

That's my code:

```js
class Box extends React.Component {

    downHandler = (e) => {
        console.log('down');
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.moveHandler);
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.upHandler);
    }

    moveHandler = (e) => {
        console.log('move');
    }

    upHandler = (e) => {
        console.log('up');
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.moveHandler);
        document.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.upHandler);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div className="circle"
                    onMouseDown={this.downHandler}></div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Box />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.container{
    width: 400px;
    height: 7px;
    background-color: #abc4f1;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 120px;
}

.circle{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #eee;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    position: absolute;
    top: -7px;
    left: calc(50% - 10px);
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reproduce your issue. I tried the code snippet and used your code in a fresh create-react-app project. Both work as expected on Chromium. Please look at your local project. Something must be different in there.

Comment: I've tried to run it on Firefox and ..it works. This makes it even more confusing.

Comment: I've noticed that the mousedown event works after releasing the mouse button but not after pressing one.